# Class scopes in Python Bottle routes

Tags: python, class, oop, scope, bottle

Inside a bottle route I am instantiating a class.

Feasibly, this page may get called simultaneously and need to create simultaneous instances of this class named "newuser" in the function.

I wanted to make sure there won't be conflicts since all instances are assigned the name "newuser" by the function.

I think this is fine since the class is created within the function call and the scope of the class should only be local to the function?

```
from bottle import route, run

class user:
    def __init__(self,id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        #Do some stuff that takes a while.



@route('/user/<id>/<name>', method = 'POST')
def test():
    newuser = user(id, name)


run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed fine; the `newuser` name is entirely local to the `test()` function scope. The instances will not be shared between calls to that route.

Comment: Great, just wanted to make sure.  Thanks.